# Is it possible to remotely perform app profiling similar to Android Studio's profiler?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, profiling, performance-testing

I am working on an Android app that will be distributed to multiple users, and I would like to perform remote app profiling on their devices. In Android Studio, the built-in profiler allows me to monitor various performance metrics like CPU usage, memory usage, and network activity. However, I need to find a way to perform similar profiling remotely on user devices without physically connecting to each device.

I tried using firebase monitoring tool but it doesnt provide details similar to android studio profiler.